# How do you change the location of an object with the code?

Tags: vb.net

I tried the code that follows, but it said it must set or assess the value, which is something i don't know how to do.

```
Something.Location.X(Something.Location.X - 100 * w)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.. Are you trying to change the value of X?

Comment: Also, X would be a property, not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

We will do it in just two short statements. We will use `top` and `left` property of an object. `Top` one will tell us about the distance from the top and `Left` will tell us the distance from the left.

### Code & Example

```
Private Sub EnterCodeHere ()
   Something.Top = 20
   Something.Left = 100 'Or 100*w (Assuming w is a variable) According to your code.
End Sub
```

I hope it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to be of help! If it satisfied your requirement, please accept this answer by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a value using "="

Perhaps like this using New Point(X,Y):

```
Something.location = New Point(something.location.x - 100 * w, something.location.y)
```